# Randomly change position of letters in a string in c++

Tags: c++, random, permutation

I have a program that creates a password with upper letters, lower letters, symbols and numbers in this order, but I want to make a subprogram that changes the order of letters in the string, making it completely random, but with out changing the letters, only the order.

Example: "ORVkgr<>74" -> ">Vr7>kgO4R<" or "Ogk4r7<RV>".

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);  // assuming v is your string
```